# How to properly deploy Influxdb on GKE without losing data

Tags: yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, influxdb, influxdb-2

I deploy influxdb v2.4 on GKE and mounted the path "/var/lib/influxdb2" to the persistent volume.

The problem is I lose data and all credentials after I manually kill the pod using kubectl and I have to setup initializations after a new pod created.

Here is my statefulset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: influxdb-dev-deploy
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb-dev-deploy
  serviceName: influxdb-dev-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb-dev-deploy
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: influxdb2
          image:  influxdb:2.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8086
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: influxdb-dev-config
            - secretRef:
                name: influxdb-dev-secret
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb2
              name: influxvol
            # - mountPath: /etc/influxdb2/configs/influxdb.conf
            #   name: influxdb-config
            #   subPath: influxdb.conf
            #   readOnly: true
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
      # volumes:
      #   - name: influxdb-config
      #     configMap:
      #       name: influxdb-dev-config
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          # preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution 
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
                operator: In
                values:
                - asia-east1-c
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: influxvol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "influxdb-dev-sc"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

storage class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: influxdb-dev-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  # fstype: ext4
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

What I expect is influxdb from the new pod will load all data and credentials from PV automatically.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: may I know the reason why you manually kill the pod? and do you have any error messages?

Comment: @JonB To keep data and credentials in a volume. Killing pod is just a way to determine if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating mountPath to

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data
```

And set INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH to `/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/influxd.bolt`